# check time variable to ensure its less than 30 days but not less than the current time

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm trying to check my string $when to ensure it's not 30 days+ into the future based on the current time(), but also not less than the current time(). For some reason strtotime is causing some sort of issue. Any suggestions on how to make this script function?

```
<?php
$when = '2011/07/11 11:22:52';

if ($when > strtotime('+30 days', time()));
{
echo "too far into the future";
header('Refresh: 10; URL=page.php');
die();
}

if ($when < time());
{
echo "less than current time";
header('Refresh: 10; URL=page.php');
die();
}

echo "pass";
header('Refresh: 10; URL=page.php');
die();
?>
```

Comment: $when is a string '2011/07/11 11:22:52', but it should be an int like the timestamp you are getting from strtotime if you want to compare both variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is you're comparing a date string to a Unix Timestamp. You need to convert `$when` to a Unix Timestamp before doing your comparisons:

```
$when = strtotime('2011-07-11 11:22:52');
```

I find using [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) makes this easy and readable (and also handles things like daylight savings time):

```
$when   = new DateTime('2011-07-11 11:22:52');
$now    = new DateTime();
$future = new DateTime('+30 days');

if ($when > $future )
{
echo "too far into the future";
header('Refresh: 10; URL=page.php');
die();
}

if ($when < $now)
{
echo "less than current time";
header('Refresh: 10; URL=page.php');
die();
}

echo "pass";
header('Refresh: 10; URL=page.php');
die();
```

Comment: Isn't it also important to add the timezone info when calling DateTime()?

Comment: I ran it in a php file and it says 2011/07/11 11:22:52 is too far into the future when it should say less than the current time. Any idea why? Thanks for the help! (Edit: yeah it still says too far into the future)

Comment: i think it defaults to the servers timezone

Comment: @derp any idea what's wrong with this script? see my comments above